# get data attribute from an image into input box on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image that contains a `data-keyword` attribute. Can anyone show me how to get its string and show it in the input field when I click on the image? I can get the text link `.special_field_link` to work but not the image `.image_keyword`. **([FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/s8nUh/176/))** The following code doesn't work:

HTML

```
<input id="a_input_id" type="text">
<a href="" class="special_field_link">@ABC<a>
<a href="" class="special_field_link">@DEF<a>
<img src="image.jpg" class="image_keyword" data-keyword="Hello" alt="pic">
```

JS:

```
$('.special_field_link,.image_keyword').click(function (e)   {
   e.preventDefault();
   if($(this).is('.image_keyword')){
      var keyword = $(this).data('keyword');
      $('#a_input_id').val(  ( $('#a_input_id').val()+" "+$(this).keyword.html() ).trim()  );      
   } 
   else {         
      $('#a_input_id').val(  ( $('#a_input_id').val()+" "+$(this).html() ).trim()  );
   }
});
```

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/M57vg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your selectors is broken:
`$('.special_field_link,image_keyword')` is missing the `.` in what should be `.image_keyword`

You are accessing the data attribute correctly with `.data('keyword')`, but you don't need the call to `.html()`:

```
var keyword = $(this).data('keyword');
$('#a_input_id').val(  ( $('#a_input_id').val()+" "+keyword ).trim()  );
```

---

Fiddle:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/s8nUh/178/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.image_keyword').click(function (e)   {
    $('#a_input_id').val($('.image_keyword').data('keyword'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example. Feel free to adapt it to your code.

```
image.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var data = image.getAttribute("data-keyword");
    input.value = data;
})
```